# Clojure Calva in VisualStudio Code loses syntax colors when switching from one window to the other

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, clojure, clojurescript, vscode-calva

When I change from one window to the other, the one I leave loses the colors of the parentheses and brackets and everything is left in white letters.

I have to go back to the previous window to get colors back. I recently updated to version 1.48.1, but it started to happen with the previous update. Any help is welcome. Thanks!!

Comment: Hello. A Calva maintainer here. I m not quite following what is actually happening. Can you file an [issue on the Calva repo](https://github.com/BetterThanTomorrow/calva/issues) with this, including a bit more detail on how to reproduce?

Comment: Forgot to say. If you file the issue from within VS Code (the Help menu, iirc) then VS Code will attach information about your system that might be relevant.

Comment: I uploaded the error to BetterThanTomorrow/calva on github through visualstudio and detail as much as I could what happens. Also add two screenshots. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I am a Calva maintainer. This is a bug that should be fixed. Here's the issue:

https://github.com/BetterThanTomorrow/calva/issues/761

I provided some more context there.